# Array Numpy Side Effect

Tags: numpy

I found a strange effect when permuting array with numpy:

```
    def permute(yy, kmax) :
     kmax=5
     kk= np.random.uniform(1,kmax)
     nn= int(np.floor(len(yy)/kk))
     yy3= np.zeros_like(yy ); 
     np.copyto(yy3,yy)

     for ii in range(0, nn): 
        ax= kk*ii-kk*nn
        aux= yy[ax]
        aux2= yy[kk*ii] 
        yy3[ax] = aux
        yy3[kk*ii] = aux2     

     return yy3
```

and

```
   yy= np.random.normal(0,1,50000)
   yy1= permute(yy,2)
   ( np.var(yy)- np.var(yy1) )

   ( np.mean(yy)- np.mean(yy1) )
```

Result is not zero !!!

Do you think this comes from reference assignment in the array ?

Comment: That's not a permutation. You're taking values from the wrong array when you swap.

Comment: Show us what it does for a small sample case.

Comment: yy=yy3 , both are same arrays.
If you execute this code, You will see that the result is not zero, whereas it should be zero.

Comment: What are the stats differences?

Answer (score 1):

I ran your function with `np.arange(10)` and got

```
1752:~/mypy$ python stack35004877.py 
0.0
0.0
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]  # yy
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]  # yy1
```

And repeated it with the large random array, with the same 0s for the statistics.

Note that your code did not permute the input

Maybe it will be clearer if I clean it up:

```
def permute(yy, kmax=5) :
     kk= np.random.randint(1,kmax)  # int rather than float
     nn= int(np.floor(len(yy)/kk))
     print(nn,kk)
     yy3= yy.copy()
     for ii in range(0, nn):
        ind1 = kk*ii
        ind2 = ind1-kk*nn
        yy3[ind2] = yy[ind2]
        yy3[ind1] = yy[ind1]    
     return yy3
```

You aren't moving anything; and with `kmax=2` you just copy every thing from `yy` to `yy3` - something you already did outside the loop.  With `kmax=5` you don't copy everything in the loop - but the initial copy hides that.

With `random.uniform()`, `kk` is a float, and the indexes are also floats. That's not desirable, but apparently not a problem.

But even if I switch the indices:

```
    yy3[ind2] = yy[ind1]
    yy3[ind1] = yy[ind2]
```

I don't permute anything, because `ind2` a negative value, that maps on to the same element as `ind1`.  `yy[-1]` is the last item of `yy`.

```
[(0, -10), (1, -9), (2, -8),... (9, -1)]
```

I could work out the details, but I think you should do that yourself - with a small test case.  And skip that initial `copyto`, that just hides errors in the iteration.  Print the details, not just summary statistics from large random arrays.

And in the long run you don't want to use an iteration like this.  You want to do the permutation with one indexing call.  But first get this version working correctly.

Comment: Hi,  The index is not int, and it caused some side effects, when No int index is used for array.